# Simplifying $2^{30} \mod 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I simply cannot seem to get my head around this subject of mathematics. It seems so counter-intuitive to me.

I have a question in my book: Simplify $2^{30}\mod 3$

This is my attempt: $2^{30}\mod 3 = (2\mod 3)^{30}$ (using the laws of congruences).

$2\mod 3$ must be equal to $2$, right? $0\cdot 3 + 2 = 2$ then the rest is "2". Therefore, I concluded that $2^{30}$ is the answer. However, my book says $1$. How can this be? Can anyone explain this to me? It's probably really easy, and I feel kind of stupid for asking, but I simply don't get it.

And also, are there any sites on the internet that provide similar problems with which you can learn the concepts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Because $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$, we have
$$ 2^{30} \equiv (-1)^{30}\equiv 1 \pmod 3.$$

Comment: Okay, I can sort of accept that based on the rule that if a-b can be divided by n, then a is congruent to b mod(n). But how was that rule derived? I simply cannot understand it, sorry.

And if 1 is right, then I must be wrong. How am I wrong? Is 2mod(3) not equal to 2?

Comment: Usually, $a \equiv b \mod n$ means that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. However, sometimes $a \pmod{n}$ will mean "the remainder of $a$ upon division by $n$". This is the unique $r$ in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ for which $a \equiv r \mod n$. With that terminology, $2 \mod 3$ equals $2$. However, $2^{30} \pmod{3}$ does not equal $2^{30}$, as this is not an element of $\{0,1,2\}$ (although $2^{30} \equiv 2^{30} \mod 3$). By noting that $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$, it is possible to actually compute the remainder of $2^{30}$ upon division by $3$, by noting it gives the same remainder as $(-1)^{30} = 1$.

Comment: @Arcthor It is important not to forget the parantheses (it's $a\equiv b\pmod n$, not $a\equiv b\mod n$, but $a\mod n$ is allowed when $a$ is alone).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\gcd(2, 3) = 1$, and so $2^{3-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. We have

$$2^{30} \equiv (2^2)^{15} \equiv 1^{15} \equiv \boxed{1} \pmod 3.$$

Comment: I guess one can verify that $2^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ without Fermat's :-)

Comment: Yes, haha. It is a handy trick for solving these sorts of problems when the exponents are a bit uglier though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to find the least non-negative residue modulo $3$ (or perhaps the residue with least absolute value. For the first the options are $0,1,2$ and for the second you can choose $-1,0,1$. The residue is essentially the same as the remainder on division by $3$.

Now $2^{30}=(2^{10})^3=(1024)^3$ is of the order of $10^9$ and the point is to find a strategy to get a smaller value.

Now $1024\equiv 1$ is easy to establish. But the easiest route, once you have correctly identified the problem, is to notice that $2\equiv -1$. Quite often, these power problems involve finding a small power which is equivalent to $\pm 1$, since these are easy to work with.

For these kinds of problems - especially if they become more advanced - you should have Fermat's Little Theorem and the Euler-Fermat theorem to hand. But first get very used to the residue being the remainder on division.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if I understand though. Is this a correct way to solve it?
We need to find the smallest absolute value b can hold, given that 2 = 3a + b?

If a=1, then b = -1.   

(-1)^30 is equal to 1, thus the answer is 1. 

Sorry if I do not understand